# google maps not loading over fullscreen image

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, css

I have been trying with no luck to load a google map over a fullscreen image, the fullscreen image code was taken from:

http://klippoglim.no/2010/06/ultimate-full-screen-images-without-flash-iphone-and-ipad-friendly/

it's basically a javacript that loads the fullscreen image, but when i try to load a google map over a div, it appears totally white as in:

Can somebody help?

EDIT:

I HAVE REMOVED ALL JAVASCRIPT, AND IT STILL IS SHOWING BLANK. NOW IT'S PURE CSS PROBLEM

Comment: Hey here are two full screen image examples, if you can make it with pure CSS you'll surely get the map overlay http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ and http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, it was a z-index issue, apparently i had to set up each one by one

Answer (score 0):

Likely, this is because you are doing the full screen overlay *after* the google maps initialization. You should do it in the other order (full screen overlay first, then google maps initialization). I can't easily change your code to test this since it is on your server, but there are two ways that you can likely make this happen (try one and if it doesn't work try the other).

(1) Move your full screen javascript tags above your google maps code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scaler.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/full.js"></script>
...
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-div"), myOptions);
```

(2) Move your google maps code inside the `$(document).ready` call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-div"), myOptions);        
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks ben, i tried both, and neither one worked, i am currently reading and re reading the scaler and full.js code

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `z-index` of the div wrapping around the maps